# I need some help understanding the tensor algebra done this problem.

Tags: physics, tensors, quantum-field-theory

I often see equations rearranged across an equal sign and I have no clue what tricks and reasoning they are using to arrive at these solutions. The only resources I can find on tensor algebra only show basic relations of vectors, the metric tenors and some other tensors, but in no way explain how to manipulate general equations in an algebra way. I suppose one could guess this solution but that is hardly ideal method as the problems get more complicated.

So here's the problem

$$
[-(k^2-m^2)g^{\mu\nu} + k^\mu k^\nu]D_{\nu \lambda}(k)=\delta^{\mu}_\lambda
$$
And the solutions is,
$$
D_{v\lambda}(k)=\frac{-g_{\nu \lambda}+k_\nu k_\lambda/m^2}{k^{2}-m^{2}}
$$

Where the Dirac symbol $\hbar=1$ and speed of light $c=1$ and $g^{\mu \nu}$ is the Minkowski metric with a $(+,-,-,-)$ signature, $m$ is mass-energy and $k^\mu$ is the momentum-energy vector.

EDIT:

Well if I understand correctly I could guess the solution to have the form $D_{\nu \lambda}(k) = a g_{\nu \lambda}+bk_\nu k_\lambda$ where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary constants. Then plug the solution into the equation do some rearranging and arrive at:

$$
k^{\mu}k_\lambda(a + b m^2)-a(k^2+m^2)\delta^\mu_\lambda = \delta^\mu_\lambda
$$

Since $ k^\mu k_\lambda$ for $ \mu \ne \lambda $ is not zero then $(a + b m^2)$ must equal zero. Now we know $a = -1/(k^2 -m^2)$ and all we have to do is solve for $b$.

The question I have is there better way to solve.

Comment: One way to look at it is that the LHS (setting aside the subtlety of upper and lower indices) is a matrix multiplication which happens to give the identity on the RHS. So you're trying to find $D_{\nu \lambda}$ by inverting the first bilinear term (which should perhaps remind you of a projection operator). Though probably the most 'physics' way is to realize that the only possible form of $D_{\nu\lambda}$ is a combination of the metric tensor and $k_\nu k_\lambda$.

Comment: Would you be satisfied with a verification, or do you actually want to see the derivation?

Comment: I have verified the solution but I haven't been able to derive the solution. I presume it's possible to derive but perhaps these problem are more like differential equations where you have to guess a solution and find the constants that make it work.

Comment: It's not quite a guess, though: You know that your answer should be bilinear and Lorentz covariant. That doesn't leave you a lot of options as far as what the answer could look like. It's an approach you'll almost certainly see again as you progress in QFT. But I'll see if I can't figure out a helpful 'deductive' approach.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that makes this problem feel unfamiliar is the presence of the metric tensor and the resulting need to distinguish upper/lower indices. We can make it look a lot more familiar if we swap the positions of the $\nu$ index in the first two terms:

$$[-(k^2-m^2)g^{\mu\nu} + k^\mu k^\nu]D_{\nu \lambda}=[-(k^2-m^2)\delta^{\mu}_{\;\nu} + k^\mu k_\nu]D^\nu_{\;\lambda}=\delta^{\mu}_{\lambda}$$

Here we have recognized that $g^\mu_{\;\nu}=g^{\mu \lambda}g_{\lambda\nu}=\delta^{\mu}_{\;\nu}$ since the signs from the spatial indices cancel out. So now we just have matrix multiplication written in a slightly unusual way; in more familiar terms, we have $$\left[-(k^2-m^2)I_4+\mathbf{k}\otimes \mathbf{k}\right]D=I_4$$ where $D$ is a matrix with entries $(D)_{\mu\nu}=D^{\mu}_{\;\nu}$ and $\mathbf{k}=(k_0,k_1,k_2,k_3)$.

Hence we now have the linear algebra problem of inverting the matrix
$$D=\left[-(k^2-m^2)I_4+\mathbf{k}\otimes \mathbf{k}\right]^{-1}.$$ The [Sherman-Morrison formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sherman-MorrisonFormula.html) comes to the rescue in handling the outer product $\mathbf{k}\otimes\mathbf{k}$: $$(A+\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v})^{-1}=A^{-1}-\frac{(A^{-1}\mathbf{u})
\otimes(\mathbf{v} A^{-1})}{1+\mathbf{v}\cdot A^{-1}\cdot \mathbf{u}}$$ with $A=-(k^2-m^2)I_4$ and $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{k}$. Some algebra gives

$$ 
D=\frac{1}{k^2-m^2}\left[-I_4 +\frac{1}{m^2}\,\mathbf{k}\otimes\mathbf{k}\right].
$$

Returning to indices, we have

$$
D^{\mu}_{\;\nu}=\frac{-\delta^{\mu}_{\;\nu}+k^\mu k_\nu/m^2}{k^2-m^2}
\implies 
D_{\mu\nu}=\frac{-g_{\mu\nu}+k_\mu k_\nu/m^2}{k^2-m^2}.
\hspace{.5cm}\blacksquare
$$

Comment: One thing I find myself disliking in my present answer is that it relies on an appeal to the Sherman-Morrison formula; I can verify that formula, but deducing it is another matter. So I could be justly accused of converting one problem into another.